# Как отправить POST запрос в Java приложение из формы, полученной с GET запроса?

Tags: java, веб-программирование, post

Есть вот такой код:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    resp.setContentType("text/html");

    String nameDB = req.getParameter("nameDB");
    String nameTable = req.getParameter("nameTable");

    String rezult = getCr(nameDB, nameTable); //получаю строку из бд.

    req.setAttribute("textA", rezult);
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher("/post.jsp");
    dispatcher.forward(req, resp);
}

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    resp.setContentType("text/html");

    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
    dispatcher.forward(req, resp);
}
```

и есть два файла:

1. index.jsp - в котором форма с полями и отправкой пост-запроса

   ```
   form id="getCreate" action="post.jsp" method="post"/form
   input name="nameDB" form="getCreate"
   input name="nameTable" form="getCreate"
   input type="submit" form="getCreate"
   ```
2. post.jsp - с полем `${textA}`, туда нужно вывести результат.

Деплою war файл на Tomcat - запускаю - ввожу данные и ... открывается пустое окно. Что я делаю не так? Как мне отправить из этой формы данные в java-приложение, чтобы там произошел коннект к бд и вытащились нужные мне данные?

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решен, нужно было указать в  `action` формы запуск этого же сервлета, т.е .именно то, что было прописано в аннотации к классу сервлета `@WebServlet("/test")`.

т.е.  `action="test"`